# What's a word meaning to use one’s hands and feet equally?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Is there a word that means being able to use one’s feet and toes like hands and fingers such as ambidextrous is to use both left and right hands equally?

Comment: Do you mean using both feet equally well as in the case of a **two-footed** football (soccer) player who can pass or shoot equally well with both feet or do you mean someone who can manipulate objects equally well with either foot in the manner of a foot painting artist or other person (an amputee or thalidomider for example) who has no hands?

Comment: What's the context? Are you talking about a person or an ape? or some other animal? See [tag:single-word-request] for requirements.

Comment: There is no such word nor, for humans, could there be. You might find a some apes and fewer monkeys who could do that, and were apes or monkeys part of your Question?

Comment: Please add an example sentence in which you would use the word.

Answer (score 10):

If you are able to use your feet like your hands your  feet are prehensile. The term you are looking for is ***prehensility.***

> ***[Prehensile feet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prehensile_feet#/search)*** are lower limbs that possess prehensility, the ability to grasp like a hand. They are most commonly observed in monkeys, some of which also possess prehensile tails, and apes. The term prehensile means "able to grasp" (from the Latin prehendere, to take hold of, to grasp).

(Wikipedia)

Comment: Just before me. Also in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/prehensile).

Comment: No, it isn't.

Where it applies, prehensility never says anything about "equal" use of feet and hands.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can offer no dictionary authority for it, but I've seen the term ***polydextrous*** used for this, meaning "capable of manipulating objects using either hands or feet". Search engines do cough up scattered uses, though most want to relate it to the compound *polydextrose*.

Comment: I started by doubting that, but to give you the benefit of that doubt, I Googled it.

Google didn't even recognise the word, let alone that meaning.

Oops!

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin - you should google harder. (-: https://www.halopedia.org/Yanme%27e mentions the word, and https://www.connected-uk.com/likes-hearts-claps-the-problem-with-social-proof/ actually references it.

Answer (score -1):

I would go for **quadrumanous**, i.e. "four hands".

> Having feet adapted for grasping ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quadrumanous))

or

> Having opposable first digits on both the feet and the hands, used for gripping and climbing. Many primates are quadrumanous. ([American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=quadrumanous))

Comment: How does that deal with "equally"?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin All four extremities are treated equally. I answered the question in the title. Otherwise, 'ambidextrous' is what you are looking for; it is used for hands, but I see no reason for not using for feet as well.

Comment: I was hoping you'd show how quadromanous included feet equally adapted for grasping. My doubt is solely about "equal" use. If you dropped "equally" from the Question I'd be happy and as it is, I think that will forever queer its own pitch.

I suggest no word fits your bill, because I believe there are no critters with equally useful hands and feet; not even the three-toed tree sloths that I guess come closest.